# How to separate and reattach columns with dplyr

Tags: r, string, cbind

I was wondering on how to separate into two diffrent chunks of the dataframe, a big dataframa and then make the column binding in dplyr

I have use the following code

```
library(string)

new = cbind(mtcars[str_detect(mtcars$am, "0"),][1:13,],
            mtcars[str_detect(mtcars$am, "1"),][,9:11])
```

But I am looking for something different and more efficient to use in a wrapping code with dplyr, forr example.

Comment: `bind_cols` instead of `cbind`? It's not clear to me what you're trying to do or what would constitute a good solution. Can you describe more of why you'd want to connect columns this way (and in a way that results in multiple columns with the same name, which'll make further analysis difficult), and what does "more efficient" mean in your context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
mtcars |>
  filter(am == 0) |>
  slice_head(n = 13) |>
  bind_col(
    filter(mtcars, am == 1)[, 9:11]
)
```

You can also use `dplyr::select` to select 9th to 11th columns.

```
mtcars |> filter(am == 1) |> select(9:11)
```

Honestly, base R is efficient enough in this case.